# Smarter way to format sql/php code?

Tags: php, sql

i have an large SQL Statement, is there any "smarter" way to format this stuff ??

```
$serverFields = 'SERVER_ID, SERVERNAME, SERVERLOCATION_ID, SERVERLOCATIONDETAIL_ID,
                             SERVEROS_ID, SERVEROSVERSION_ID, IP_BACKEND, IP_FRONTEND, IP_BACKUP,
                             SERVERREMOTETOOL_IDS, LOGIN, DESCRIPTION, TIME_INSERT, TIME_UPDATE,
                             CHANGE_USER, MANDATOR_ID, TIVOLI_UPDATABLE, TIVOLI_LAST_SCAN,
                             TIVOLI_LAST_UPDATE, WINDOMAIN_ID, PROCESSORCOUNT, OS_ID, PHYSICAL_MEMORY_KB';
```

$osFields = 'OSLANG_ID, OSARCH_ID, OSSUBVERSION_ID, OSMINORVERSION_ID, OSMAJORVERSION_ID, OSTYPE_ID';

$processorFields = 'PROCESSORMODEL_ID, PROCESSORMANUFACTURER_ID';

$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT %s , %s , %s FROM %s s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            (OS JOIN
                OSSUBVERSION USING (OSSUBVERSION_ID)) JOIN
                OSMINORVERSION USING (OSMINORVERSION_ID) JOIN
                OSMAJORVERSION USING (OSMAJORVERSION_ID)
            )USING (OS_ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN (
              PROCESSORMODEL JOIN PROCESSORMANUFACTURER USING(PROCESSORMANUFACTURER_ID)
            )USING (PROCESSORMODEL_ID) WHERE
                %s = :id AND MANDATOR_ID = :mandatorId",
                $serverFields, $osFields, $processorFields, $this->_tableName, $this->_identifier);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd write and indent it all somewhat differently, but whether it's "smarter" is up to you:

```
$sql = sprintf("
    SELECT %s, %s, %s
    FROM %s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OS USING (OS_ID)
    JOIN OSSUBVERSION USING (OSSUBVERSION_ID)
    JOIN OSMINORVERSION USING (OSMINORVERSION_ID)
    JOIN OSMAJORVERSION USING (OSMAJORVERSION_ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PROCESSORMODEL USING (PROCESSORMODEL_ID)
    JOIN PROCESSORMANUFACTURER USING (PROCESSORMANUFACTURER_ID)
    WHERE %s = :id
    AND MANDATOR_ID = :mandatorId
", $serverFields, $osFields, $processorFields, $this->_tableName, $this->_identifier);
```